# rails app how to send 2d array using postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to send a 2d array in this format:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5]]
```

this is passed to parameter

`params[:order][:product_ids_and_quantities]`

I have tried

```
Key: order[product_ids_and_quantities][][]
Value: [1, 4]
Key: order[product_ids_and_quantities][][]
Value: [2, 5]
```

And

```
Key: order[product_ids_and_quantities]
Value: [[1,4],[2,5]]
```

But it's not working. I always get a string in rails

Comment: @Зелёный not really. I think you can use any other tools. It's about rails way of dealing with parameters.

Comment: Have you tried sending the request in the "raw" (`application/json`) format?